# How to get rid of path traversal issues in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-applications

The application allows user input to control or influence paths or file names that are used in file system operations. This information can be further used to attack the application which may lead to sensitive data leakage and exploitation.

How to Perform validation and sanitization on the user input before processing it.?

Comment: For what to actually do, see the answer from @YorkChen. As this is a Veracode finding (based on the wording :) ), note that even with the correct mitigations in place, Veracode still identifies this issue sometimes. In that case, if you are sure it's not vulnerable anymore, you can mark it as 'mitigated by design'.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid Path Traversal you can,

1. Make white list (or restriction) for the user input,
   for example, only allow user to input specific file names, not including chars like "/" or "\" and so on.
2. Configure proper permission for the system folder,
   for example, put the resource files that you allow user to visit in specific folder, and only give permission to that folder for the program account. In this case, system help you prevent from path traversal attacks.

Comment: Actually this happens in the url . In the url if user adds ../../../ then the path traversal occurs.so in this case how can we resolve this issues?

Comment: Do validation for the url in your program, before returning the content.

Comment: How to perform validation for URL links?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-do-i-check-entered-url-is-valid-or-not

can we validate url like the code below?

void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
 var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 // validate thi surl using Regex and re found faulty then redirect... it
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of searchers, I have made a reasonable starting point to work out if there is a traversal attempt on a file. This assumes a filename like 'somefile.pdf', not 'c:/tmp/somefile.pdf'.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is to guage whether someone is trying a directory traversal attack.
/// I.e. they should be requesting 'somefilename.pdf'
/// but they request '../anotherlocation/someotherfilename.pdf
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">The file name to check</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool IsDirectoryTraversing(string fileName)
{
    bool isTraversing = false;

    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
    {
        return isTraversing;
    }

    // Url decode to reveal sneaky encoded attempts e.g. '%2f' (/) or '%2e%2e%2f' (../)
    var decodedFileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileName);

    if(decodedFileName.Contains("/") || 
        decodedFileName.Contains(@"\") ||
        decodedFileName.Contains("$") ||
        decodedFileName.Contains("..") ||
        decodedFileName.Contains("?"))
    {
        isTraversing = true;
    }

    return isTraversing;
}
```